# VS2005 Options Generate Method Stub not working

Tags: visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, stubbing

Ok I installed the linq preview(May 2006) and it seems to have screwed me up. Now the one the of the most important features in VS2005 is not working anymore (Options Generate Method Stub (Shift+Alt+F10)). I used to get this message every time I would start a project
("This is an unsupported version of Microsoft Visual C# 3.0 / Microsoft Visual Basic 9.0. Therefor, many features may not work as expected.").
I uninstalled it and the feature is still not working but the error message is gone now. 
If you don't know what I'm talking about if you type this simple code in you visual studio code editor: "string myString = GetString();" without declaring GetString() first, you will get a smart tag under GetString() and when you select it, you get a drop down that asks if you want to auto generate this method stub.

Is there a way to re-enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you installed this ancient version but did you also properly install dotNet 2?

You may have to re-install by hand.

Comment: Well lets not dwell on past mistakes :-). I'll try reinstalling the 2.0 framework.

Comment: Well I had to repair/re-install VS2005 to fix it. Rest assured I will never make this mistake again.